# What is the meaning of this Snap Pops scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, we-are-what-we-are

Near the end of the first third of the movie We Are What We Are, there is a scene of a kid asking for some food, and his sister putting some "Snap Pops" into his glass of milk. Then the kid whispers: "Snap Pops!", and his sister responds with eating one from the pack. Then the other scene follows.

[image]

The "Snap Pops" cereal brand appears to be fictional, so it's not a product placement situation, but the scene is so conveniently short. I'm not sure what it means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scene is showing that the family is supposed to be [fasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fasting) at the time. The fasting is part of their annual ritual.

> The fast is broken when they sit down to eat their people stew.

However, as a young child, Rory either doesn't understand why he's not allowed to eat, or just doesn't care because he's hungry.

> It also foreshadows Rose's later rebellion. She's old enough to understand the fasting. She shouldn't be allowing her brother to eat, much less eating herself.